# How to use Activator.CreateInstance to create instance of class when user presses button

Tags: c#, winforms, class, oop, activator

[image]

```
class Person
{


    //Default Constructor
    public Person()
    {
        name_private = "";
        attr_private = 0.0;
    }

    //Overloaded Constructor
    public Person(string name, double attr)
    {
        name_private = name;
        attr_private = attr;
    }

    //Member Variables
    private string name_private;
    private double attr_private;


}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private void createPersonBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Object obj =   Activator.CreateInstance<Person>();

        //Person person_1 = new Person();
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
How can I create an instance of the person class when someone presses the Create Person button. Rather than naming the instance of the class a generic name like person_1, I want the name of the instance to be the text in the top text box. I have read the MSDN article on Activator.CreateInstance and I have determined that it is the best way to achieve this. However I don't know how to properly overload it. I need to be able to reference the instance of the class as the name of the person not as obj.

Simplicity is the goal here.

Comment: You can't set instance name dynamically.And why instance name is so important for you???

Comment: How else would I differentiate between objects if every time the button is pressed, the instance would be overwritten.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your point, do you want to create a Person instance and set it's `name` field to textBox1.text ?

Comment: that is exactly my point, I just didn't know how to phrase it correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to maintain all the "Persons" that are created you will need to stick them in some form of a container.   Put a field in your form class of type like below.

private List _persons = new List();

Then, when you are handling the button click you can just add your dynamically created person to this collection.  Question is a bit tough given you are not providing much context into exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

_persons.add(Activator.CreateInstance());

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your description, you want to store each created person. And as you said you can't store it in a `person1` for instance.

You should have a list of created persons and store them in it. There's no need to use `Activator.CreateInstance()`

```
List<Person> CreatedPersons = new List<Person>();

private void createPersonBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tempPerson = new Person(); //No need to use Activator.CreateInstance<Person>();
    // Fill the tempPerson with form text boxes.

    createdPersons.Add(tempPerson);
}
```

`Activator.CreateInstance` is useful for **some other scenarios** which the type of creating object is not fixed and you want to pass it as parameter. For example in the following example you want to create an instance of `type`:

```
Type type;
type = GetCreatingType(); // Some algorithm to find out what type to create;

var instance = new type(); // This doesn't work
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // But this works.
```